# Problem with loading invalid csv with CsvHelper

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I have a `.csv` file separated with commas and string quoted with `''`. Problem is when inside quoted string there is a `"` or a `'` and I don't know how to solve this. Is there any solution so it ignores `'` and `"` inside quoted text?

For example

```
'this is your's 25" string'
```

My config code is

```
CsvConfiguration csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    Delimiter = ",",
    HasHeaderRecord = true,
    Quote = '\'',
};
```

Comment: Why not tell whoever produced this invalid CSV to fix it? You can't just guess where each field starts and ends if quoting is wrong. What if the quoted field contained more quotes, or commas? Quote characters that appear inside a field should be doubled. A valid field would be `"this is your's 25"" string"` using the default text quote (double quote) or `'this is your''s 25" string'` using the custom quote. Or, you can tell whoever created this to use something that doesn't usually appear in text, like `|`, `§` or `¤`

Comment: See [RFC-1480](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) which specifies the format for CSV files. If strings are quoted, they should use double quotes and double quotes inside the string should be escaped using another double quote e.g. `"this is your's 25"" string"`. You should really speak to whoever is providing the invalid CSV to report the issue and have them fix it.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos i can tell them but they dont care :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

You can come close by catching `BadDataFound`. Unfortunately, it could either corrupt the data or throw an exception if there is a line break inside quotes, where there is also bad data.  There is also a chance a delimiter inside the quotes won't get processed correctly.

```cs
void Main()
{
    List<(int,string)> badRecords = new List<(int,string)>();
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Quote = '\'',
        Escape = '\'',
        BadDataFound = args => badRecords.Add((args.Context.Parser.Row, args.RawRecord))
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Id,MyProperty\n1,'this is, your's 25\" string'"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>().ToList();
    }
    
    foreach (var record in badRecords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bad record at Row: {0}, RawRecord: {1}", record.Item1, record.Item2);
    }   
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```